# Powershell uninstall by vendor/publisher

Tags: powershell, wmic

I'm trying to blanket uninstall various uninstalls for Autodesk. Using wmic I was able to get the majority of the uninstalls by doing:

```
wmic product where "name like 'auto%%'" call uninstall
```

But that still left a bunch of the applications installed. Then I tried with powershell and got to the point that I can find the remaining installs with:

```
Get-ItemProperty HKLM:\Software\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\* | Select-Object Displayname, UninstallString | Format-Table -AutoSize | findstr Autodesk
```

But I'm stumped on how to run each of the uninstall strings found. Aside from just Autodesk I would like to figure this out so I can blanket uninstall other vendor installs in the future, not just by application name.

Answer (score 0):

You can try below first:

```
$UninstallApps = Get-WmiObject Win32_Product | Where-Object {$_.Name -like '*Application1*' -or $_.Name -like '*Application2*'}

$UninstallApps.Uninstall()
```

Then for anything under HKLM you can try do the following:

```
$UninstallPaths = @( 
    'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall', 
    'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall') 

$UninstallSearchFilter = {$_.GetValue('DisplayName') -like 'Auto*'} 
 
Foreach ($Path in $UninstallPaths) { 
    if (Test-Path $Path) { 
        Get-ChildItem $Path | Where $UninstallSearchFilter |  
        Foreach { Start-Process 'C:\Windows\System32\msiexec.exe' "/x $($_.PSChildName) /qn" -Wait} 
    } 
}
```

Comment: Neither of those worked, I'm still left with the same amount of installed. I can get the uninstall string, I'm almost wondering if I can write the uninstall strings to an array and run them.

Answer (score 0):

Use the field **'vendor'** instead of **'name'**.

Example:

```
wmic product where "vendor like 'Autodesk%'" call uninstall /nointeractive
```

Note: In the where statement I used **like** instead of **=** since sometimes Autodesk is registered as 'Autodesk, inc.'